# How do I convert a 3D image array into a 2D image array in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, image-processing

I have a three-dimensional array of a image stored in a NumPy array. Using an algorithm, I converted the RGB image into [grayscale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grayscale#Noun). But in the third dimension the RGB values are same (for gray, the RGB values are same) and I want to convert all the three values into one and thus converting the three-dimensional array into two-dimensional one.

I.e, the current three-dimensional array is:

```
[[[24 24 24] [36 36 36].......[108 108 108]]
 [[196 196 196] [45 45 45] ..... [90 90 90]]
 ...........................................
 ...........................................
 [[80 80 80] [74 74 74] ..........[127 127 127]]]
```

The 2D array I want is:

```
[[24 36 ..........108]
 [196 45 ......... 90]
 [80 74 ..........127]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: .. `arr[...,0]`?

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to repair your conversion algorithm so that it returns a single number for each grey value rather than 3 numbers.

Comment: Can you use an already existing algorithm? `from skimage.color import rgb2gray`; `grey_im=rgb2gray(color_im)`

Comment: Using an already existing algorithm from opencv or skiimage returns a 2d array but I am trying to implement my own algorithm @Brenlla

Answer (score 3):

That can be accomplished using slice syntax

`a[:,:,0]`